# php Google Calendar API create not all-day recurring events

Tags: php, icalendar

I want to create a **not** all-day recurring yearly event with this string:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20130710T120000Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20130710T130000Z
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=20160710T130000Z
```

Event start: 2013-07-10 12:00
Event end: 2013-07-10 13:00
Until: 2016-07-10 13:00

This string is creating an all-day yearly recurring event even when i send the start and finish time.
Can someone help me with the string i have to send to Google?
I believe it's not a code problem since the events are beeing created but are beeing marked as all-day.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event does not follow RFC5545. If you have a VALUE=DATE parameter, the value should be YYYYMMDD. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.4
. In other words, you probably want to just remove the VALUE=DATE parameter.

Comment: Yes mate thanks a lot for your reply, i figure it out yesterday but i couldn't reply to my own post, but any case you are exacly right, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest would be to not define the dtend as by default it would mean that this is a full day.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i want exactly the opposite, a not all-day event. I already solved the problem but i only can post the solution after 8h.